# Bayes Formula for a problem?

Tags: probability, probability-distributions

So I am taking exams in Probabilities next week and this one comes from last year's exams period. The problem is the following.

> A system of 5 quantities is functional if and only if at least one of its 5 quantities is functional. Every quantity of the system functions with probability equal to $p_1$ if the temperature of the environment is more than $30$ degrees Celsius and with probability $p_2$ otherwise. At noon, temperature $T$ follows a uniform distribution $T \sim U(27,38)$. If the quantities of the system function independently, find the probability that the system functions at noon.

First of all, I think that it's Bayes formula for this one, but I am having a hard time connecting the temperature, quantities and the system functioning all at once.

Any ideas would be appreciated a lot! Thank you!

Comment: There might be a typo. Did you forget to include a number? "if the temperature of the environment is more than degree Celsius"

Comment: @probablyme you are right thnx!

Comment: It's still missing. All that shows up is a `$` sign. If you want to write a specific value enclose it with \$ signs. So `$20$` shows $20$. `\$` shows the symbol \$.

Comment: @probablyme I know, I tried twice but now I think its fixed :D

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the best way to approach this is use the Law of Total Probability (see [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_total_probability)). If we denote the event that $T > 30$ by $A$, the complementary event that $T \leq 30$ by $A^C$, and the event that the system functions by $B$, then the law of total probability tells us that $$P(B) = P(B|A)P(A) + P(B|A^C) P(A^C) $$
This basically allows us to consider all of the possible cases for the temperature in determining the probability of the chance for the system to function.

Because $T \sim U(27,38)$, then we see that $P(A) = \frac{8}{11}$ and $P(A^C) = \frac{3}{11}$. What we have left to determine are $P(B|A)$ and $P(B|A^C)$. If we know that event $A^C$ occurs (meaning the temperature is less than or equal to 30 degrees), then we know that each of the five quantities independently functions with probability $p_1$. Therefore the event that the system functions is equivalent to the complement of the event in which all five quantities malfunction. Each quantity malfunctions with probability $1-p_1$, and therefore all five malfunction with probability $(1-p_1)^5$. It follows that $$P(B|A^C) = 1 - (1-p_1)^5$$ and we can similarly compute that $$P(B|A) = 1 - (1-p_2)^5 $$ Putting this all together gives us that $$P(B) = \frac{3}{11} \left(1 - (1-p_2)^5 \right) + \frac{8}{11}\left(1 - (1-p_1)^5 \right) = 1 - \frac{8(1-p_1)^5 + 3(1-p_2)^5}{11} $$

Comment: Thnx man! Tbh I was between total probability and Bayes formula but it seems I have not yet been able to understand the proper use of these two. I'll keep trying. Thank you again :)

Answer (score 1):

I don't think Bayes' Theorem is needed for this question.

Since $T\sim U[27,38]$, we have that $P(27\leq T\leq30)=\frac{3}{11}$ and $P(30\leq T\leq38)=\frac{8}{11}$.

Finding the probability that a single quantity is functional...
\begin{align}
P(\text{a single quantity functions at noon})&=P(T\leq 30\text{ and functions})+P(T\geq30\text{ and functions})\\
&=\frac{3}{11}\cdot p_2+\frac{8}{11}\cdot p_1
\end{align}

Thus, $P(\text{a single quantity does not function at noon})=1-\left(\frac{3}{11}\cdot p_2+\frac{8}{11}\cdot p_1\right)=1-\frac{3}{11}p_2-\frac{8}{11}p_1$.

Since the quantities are independent, we can use the simple multiplication law...
\begin{align}
P(\text{at least one of 5 quantities functional})&=1-P(\text{none of 5 quantities functional})\\
&=1-\left(1-\frac{3}{11}p_2-\frac{8}{11}p_1\right)^5
\end{align}